# Can the same credit card be used for multiple Apple ID accounts?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

Can the same credit card be used for multiple Apple ID accounts (except for the Family plan case of course)?

Any link to official Apple statement would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why ***wouldn't*** you be able to associate a single credit card with multiple Apple IDs?

I've done it when I used to have a work-issued iPhone along with my personal iPhone (so I could expense work-related apps, if needed).

If you use the Family option, the same card is used for purchases on all connected accounts.

See [Change or remove your Apple ID payment information](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201266).

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to set up a European account with US credit card? But you couldn't.

Comment: @DataGreed regions aren't part of the question

Answer (score 1):

Just do it and work with Apple support if you find yourself blocked on the second account. You’ll get a clear reading if Apple has a policy to prevent this in short order. You might also find that the policies in each country for payment vary so anyone here saying it works in the US might be moot for you if in the European Union, there are different rules or laws or policies or vice versa.